# Is there a way to trigger Json response in PHP PDO after query run

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

I'm new to development and while working on a project I ran into a problem. this is my first practice with PHP PDO.

I'm trying to get a response on my Booking.php page via `json_encode()`
but there seems to be a problem as I can't seem to get the response after the SQL query is executed.

My code for JQuery is:

```
 var formdata = new FormData(this);
        formdata.append('createbooking','1');
        $.ajax({
        url:"functions/functions.php",
        type:"POST",
        data: formdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(response){
            $('.alert').hide();
            var res = response;
            if(res.hasOwnProperty('success')){
                $('#tourbooking').append('<div class="alert alert-success">'+res.success+'</div>');
                //setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = 'user_profile.php'; }, 1500);
            }else if(res.hasOwnProperty('error')){
                $('#tourbooking').append('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+res.error+'</div>');
            }
        }
```

And the PHP part is :

```
            if(isset($_POST['createbooking'])){
        if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) || empty($_POST['first_name'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'First Name Field Empty.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['last_name']) || empty($_POST['last_name'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Last Name Field Empty.')); exit;
        }else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Please Enter Correct Email Address.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['contact']) || empty($_POST['contact'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Password Field Empty.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['tourname']) || empty($_POST['tourname'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Tour name not set.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['tourduration']) || empty($_POST['tourduration'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Tour duration not set.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['tourtype']) || empty($_POST['tourtype'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Tour type not set.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['price']) || empty($_POST['price'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Price not set.')); exit;
        }else{
            $stmt = $conn -> prepare("INSERT INTO tour_bookings
                    (c_name_first, c_name_last, c_email, c_contact_no, c_message,
                    booked_tour_name, tour_duration, booked_tour_type, c_no_people, booked_tour_price) 
                    VALUES
                    (:firstname, :lastname, :email, :contact, :message,
                    :tname, :tduration, :ttype, :gsize, :price)");

            $data = [
                'firstname' => ($_POST['first_name']),
                'lastname' => ($_POST['last_name']),
                'email' => ($_POST['email']),
                'contact' => ($_POST['contact']),
                'message' => ($_POST['message']),
                'tname' => ($_POST['tourname']),
                'tduration' => ($_POST['tourduration']),
                'ttype' => ($_POST['tourtype']),
                'gsize' => ($_POST['groupsize']),
                'price' => ($_POST['price'])
            ];
            
            $response = $stmt->execute($data);

           if($response){

                echo json_encode(array('success'=>'Booking Confirmed Successfully! An Email containing your Booking Information has been sent to your email')); exit;

            }else{
                
                echo json_encode(array('error'=>$response)); exit;

            }

            }
        }
```

The Json_encode part works like a charm in the if statements above the execution query code:

```
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) || empty($_POST['first_name'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'First Name Field Empty.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['last_name']) || empty($_POST['last_name'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Last Name Field Empty.')); exit;
        }else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Please Enter Correct Email Address.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['contact']) || empty($_POST['contact'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Password Field Empty.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['tourname']) || empty($_POST['tourname'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Tour name not set.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['tourduration']) || empty($_POST['tourduration'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Tour duration not set.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['tourtype']) || empty($_POST['tourtype'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Tour type not set.')); exit;
        }else if(!isset($_POST['price']) || empty($_POST['price'])){
            echo json_encode(array('error'=>'Price not set.')); exit;
        }
```

but after `$stmt->execute($data);` no line of code seems to work.
Is there a problem with the way I'm executing the query?
P.S. the Data is getting added in the Database but the response part is not working.

Comment: _no line of code seems to work_. Open error logs and paste details in your question.

Comment: I don't believe getResult() is a valid method for a PDOStatement object.

Comment: Just as an aside: Putting `echo json_encode(array('error'=>$response))` in the `else` after you've just determined (via `if(isset($response)){
`) that `$response` doesn't exist is not a logical thing to do

Comment: Also, make sure you've got PHP set up to log errors, and PDO set to throw them. Then if your query is failing, or there's another PHP error, you can look in the log file and see details of it. See https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors for details of how to configure that.

Comment: And Alex Howansky is right... A PDO statement object doesn't have a getResult function - did you [check the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)? It's unclear where you got the idea to use a function with that name? So probably PHP is throwing an error about that.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, a jQuery problem, or a MySQL problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: What does "not working" actually mean? What have you observed? What debugging have you done?

Comment: I was trying to use 'getResult()' before but then I removed it. I want to capture the query's response that the data did pass to the Database (via Json_encode()) but no matter how I try to do it the code after the execute line doesn't work even after removing if from if else  statement. if the success response is triggered before the query then the query doesn't work... I don't know what i'm doing wrong the same code structure is working in another project (NOT PDO) just fine.

Comment: ADyson not working means that the success function is not getting triggered for some reason nor the error response after the query executes. the code works like a charm before the query execute. for debugging I tried to re-write the whole else case structure but again if I try to run the success response before the query it works but the query dose not execute.

Comment: "the success function is not getting triggerd"...ok, well maybe if you'd also handled jQuery's "error" callback, that would be being triggered instead. Or you can use your browser's Developer Tools (specifically the Console and Network areas) to see what happened to the AJAX request, and what the raw response from the server was. If you're working with AJAX and JavaScript you should hopefully be familiar with these tools already...?

Comment: Yes I did use console.log to try to get an output but no use no exceptions were thrown out. I can't wrap my head around it. I rechecked the code multiple times to figure out what's wrong but alas no use.  And no weather it's success or error both not working after the execute line.

Comment: `I did use console.log to try to get an output`...where? if "success" isn't being executed, then putting a log command in there won't be executed either.  Did you look at the Network tool too - open that before you run your code. Then run your code and watch it. You can see the request to `functions.php` in there, you can click on it and see what it sent to the server, and see what the response code and content was, if any.

Comment: ADyson I did not know about the Network part thanks for that. I got this in the network response Notice: Undefined index: groupsize in C:\xampp\htdocs\TTours\functions\functions.php on line 43
{"success":"Booking Confirmed Successfully! An Email containing your Booking Information has been sent to your email"}

Comment: as I set the value for group size the Response got successful. Now just need to get a way to set a value to groupsize if group is not selected thanks for the help...

Comment: Either give it a default value, or change your PHP code so it checks for the existence of that variable (e.g. using `isset()`) before it tries to use it. You seem to be validating all the other fields that way, so why not that one?

Comment: Got It ! Thank you ADyson for guiding me through it.

Answer (score 1):

Got the problem solved. the problem was with the value of groupsize was not being assigned as the form was submitted with single or couple status. I tried to hide the group size field instead of disabling it and it worked just fine.
huge thanks to ADyson for guiding me through what I should be looking for and where to look for it.